# I can't get a select box value until is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-selectbox

I have this selectBox:

```
<select class="span2" name="filterYear" id="filterYear" style="margin-right:10px;">
    <% for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) { %>
        <% if (years[i] == selectedYear) { %>
            <option value="<%= years[i] %>" selected="selected"><%= years[i] %></option>
        <% } else { %>
             <option value="<%= years[i] %>"><%= years[i] %></option>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

With this js function:

```
$("#filterYear").change(function(e){        
    $.ajax({
        url: '/changeYear/' + this.value,
        type: 'GET'
        });                
    }
});
```

And this is the node.js function. I get the value of the selectBox and set it to another variable:

```
exports.changeYear = function (req, res) {        
    var year = req.param('year');    
    req.session.maindashSelectedYear = year;        
};
```

The problem is this: If a user doesn't click the selectBox, the function `req.param('year')` does not work... But if a user does click it, everything works fine! I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Well, that is the expected behavior of your code. You only send a GET request when the `change` event triggers in the select which is when the user selects something. Can you show **where and when exactly** `req.param('year')` doesn't work?

Comment: where does the selectedYear variable come from. change only triggers when something changes. In your case, nothing changes until the user clicks

Comment: I need the year value when the user click another selectBox (month). Only if previously the user clicks in the year selectBox I get the year value when the user click in month box. If the user yet not clicked the year box and clicked in month box the year value is undefined. This happens the first time when the user enters the screen (if he is not select yet another year before).

Comment: would you please show the route where did you use exports,changeYear function?

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameter from url like this

```
  req.params.years
```